# ADAL JS - Acquire token: Token Renewal Operation failed due to timeout

Tags: javascript, timeout, token, adal

I'm working in order to leverage the usage of the AD for authentication and authorization of several applications, and I'm currently studying how to implement said process.

This is for a Web-Browser to Web-Application flow.

I create an AuthenticationContext instance and use it to sign in, and that much functions normally. 
(Code organization simplified for demo purposes)

```
this.adal = new AuthenticationContext({
    tenant: this.tenantId,
    clientId: this.clientId,
    redirectUri: this.redirectUri,
    callback: this.loginCallback,
    popUp: true
});

this.adal.login();
```

It is when I try to acquire a Token that the behaviour becomes fishy.
It is relevant to say that this application's registry in the AD has the permission "Sign in and read user profile" on Microsoft Graph API.

```
this.adal.acquireToken("https://graph.microsoft.com", function(error, token) {
    console.log(error);
    console.log(token);
});
```

The error is written to the console as follows: "Token renewal operation failed due to timeout"; whilest token is written as a null object. A brief look at the "Network" tab while inspecting the page with Chrome reveals such a resource:

```
authorize?response_type=token&client_id=xxxxx&resource=xxxxx&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080(.....)
```

The Status for said resource is 302.

Got any clues? Thanks!

Comment: Try looking at the network trace to see if the request is actually hanging or there's some kind of error being generated. Also, have you tried it a few times and it's consistently happening?

Answer (score 2):

Ok.. it seems like I've figured it out, with a little help from this article [click for article](https://shweta612.wordpress.com/2017/06/14/adal-js-token-renewal-operation-failed-due-to-timeout/) and this [click for very cool info](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/wiki/FAQs)

I've replaced the following bit of code, in the login callback

```
this.adal.acquireToken("https://graph.microsoft.com", function(error, token) {
    console.log(error);
    console.log(token);
});
```

for this:

```
var cachedToken = this.adal.getCachedToken(client_id_goes_here);
    if (cachedToken) {
        this.adal.acquireToken("https://graph.microsoft.com", function(error, token) {
            console.log(error);
            console.log(token);
        });
    }
```

And finally just add this line of code to a function that is run after the acquireToken method redirects to the page:

```
this.adal.handleWindowCallback();
```

Hope this is helpful for others who run by this issue!

Comment: It was very helpful for me, especially the articles. Take a look at them if you have this kind of problems

Comment: if think it's `if (!cachedToken) {..}` instead of `if (cachedToken) {..}` ...
if it's cached, it means a non-expired access token already exists so no need to acquire anew